# How to implement a rate limiter in Scala?

Tags: scala, guava, akka

I would like to use a RateLimiter in Scala to limit frequency of a method call.

I need something similar to Guava implementation:
http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html

I know I can use Guava natively, but I would like to know if there is a better native solution in Scala, with or without Akka

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally, I'd use Guava.  But you can create your own without too much hardship using futures.

```
class RateLimiter(delayMs: Int) {
  private[this] var last: Long = System.currentTimeMillis
  private[this] val done = scala.actors.Futures.alarm(0)
  def request = {
    val now = System.currentTimeMillis
    val elapsed = synchronized {
      val elapsed = now - last
      last = if (elapsed < delayMs) last+delayMs else now
      elapsed
    }
    if (elapsed < delayMs) scala.actors.Futures.alarm(delayMs-elapsed)
    else done
  }
}
```

You then create a limiter for each method or set of methods you want to limit access to, and start the method with a call to `request()`; this will use a `Future` to block if needed.  If you want something other than a spacing of at least so-many milliseconds, you just have to change a little math and/or keep track of a little more state.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [some wrappers around Guava's `RateLimiter`](http://nxt.flotsam.nl/rate-limiting), to allow you to turn any function into its rate-limited version. Have some doubts if Guava's RateLimiter is actually they way to go. It's `acquire()` call is blocking the thread, even it wouldn't be blocking the thread, there's a fair chance you're introducing something that could blow the top of your heap.